# How to on the repeater show only top 10 item and when click expand button show all repeater item

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater and bind it. But I want to show top 10 item template and when click expand button show all item template.
I want to use Bootstrap and JavaScript.

Source code: repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="MoreBrandSelectionRepeater" runat="server">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <div style="color: rgb(0, 83, 167)" class="row collapse in" id="demo">
                                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                <label style="font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; font-weight: 100; cursor: pointer">
                                                    <asp:CheckBox AutoPostBack="true" ID="BrandCheckBox" name='<%#"Brand-"+Eval("ebrand") %>' runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="BrandCheckBox_CheckedChanged" />
                                                    <%#(Eval("fbrand")) %>
                                                </label>

                                                <asp:Label Visible="false" Text='<%#Eval("ebrand")%>' ID="BrandLabel" runat="server" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
                                                <%#(Eval("ebrand")) %>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <FooterTemplate>
                                        <button type="button" id="expand Button" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span>کمتر
                                        </button>

                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind : repeater bind

```
SqlDataAdapter daBrand = new SqlDataAdapter("Select distinct top(10) RTRIM(LTRIM(Substring(brand,0,CharIndex(N'#',brand)))) as fBrand, RTRIM(LTRIM(Substring(brand,CharIndex(N'#',brand)+1,(len(brand)-CharIndex(N'#',brand))))) as eBrand from product WHERE ([Cat" + catLevel + "] = N'" + destName + "' )", con);
                DataTable dtBrand = new DataTable();
                daBrand.Fill(dtBrand);
                BrandSelectionRepeater.DataSource = dtBrand;
                BrandSelectionRepeater.DataBind();
```

I have when repeater item template is more than 10 show only  10 item  when I click button show all item.

Please help me.